# Ensure Exhaustiveness and Correctness of Object based on Const Array of Objects

Tags: typescript

Given the following `ROUTES`:

```js
const ROUTES = [
  { name: "Login", path: "/login", id: "login" },
  { name: "Registration", path: "/registration", id: "registration" },
  { name: "Settings", path: "/settings", id: "settings" },
] as const;
```

How can I create a type (`SomeType`) for which:

1. every `id` is used as a key
2. every `path` is used as a value
3. all keys (`id`) are matched 1-to-1 with their value (`path`) given the `ROUTES` configuration

For example:

```
# correct
const correctIdToPaths: SomeType = {
  login: "/login",
  registration: "/registration",
  settings: "/settings", 
} as const

# wrong
const duplicatedValues: SomeType = {
  login: "/registration", # error, id "login" does not match path "/registration"
  registration: "/registration",
  settings: "/settings", 
} as const

# wrong
const missingKey: SomeType = {
  login: "/login",
  registration: "/registration",
} as const # error: "settings" is missing
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `typeof ROUTES[number]` to get a union of the `Route`s in the array, and create a mapped type where you [remap the key](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to the id:

```
type SomeType = {[Route in typeof ROUTES[number] as Route['id']]: Route['path']}
// type SomeType = {login: "/login", registration: "/registration", settings: "/settings"}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/NrDa5W)